# HTC One M7 DCIM folder isn't listed by HTC Sync Manager

Tags: file-management, htc-one

Running the most recent software update on my phone and the most recent HTC Sync Manager and I can't see DCIM folder in HTC Sync Manager. I can see it via HTC native File Manager app, though.

I had run into this problem before and it resolved itself somehow. Anyone else running into this problem? Anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check inside storage. The folder that is first presented seems to be different under lollipop on my M7. But storage\emulated\0\ has all the folders that used to be there!

Comment: Nope, not there.